# Split column and convert empty values to null in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to fill an empty value as null when I split a column in Spark. Example:

```
| A        |
| 1.2.3    |
| 4..5     |
```

I was looking for:

| A | A split 1 | A split 2 | A split 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2.3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4..5 | 4 | null | 5 |

I got:

| A | A split 1 | A split 2 | A split 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2.3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4..5 | 4 |  | 5 |

My code is:

```
df.withColumn("A", when(split(col("A"), "\\.") =!= lit(""), split(col("A"), "\\."))
```

However, I got an error because due to a type mismatch:

> array(string) is not a string.

It could be possible to find a solution without using a UDF?

Many thanks

Comment: Assuming split part is resolved, 
do you want to create new columns from arrays? Or just want to replace the empty string with null inside the split array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split then when getting array items as columns use `when` to change to null if element is empty :

```
// n is the max array size from split (in your example it's 3)
val n = 3

val df1 = df.withColumn(
    "ASplit",
    split(col("A"), "[.]")
  ).select(
    Seq(col("A")) ++ (0 to n-1).map(i =>
      when(col("ASplit")(i) === "", lit(null)).otherwise(col("ASplit")(i)).as(s"A split $i")
    ): _*
  )
    
//+-----+---------+---------+---------+
//|    A|A split 0|A split 1|A split 2|
//+-----+---------+---------+---------+
//|1.2.3|        1|        2|        3|
//| 4..5|        4|     null|        5|
//+-----+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `transform` the split result by replacing empty values with null:

```
val result = df.withColumn(
    "split",
    expr("transform(split(A, '\\\\.'), x -> case when x = '' then null else x end)")
).select($"A", $"split"(0), $"split"(1), $"split"(2))

result.show
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|    A|split[0]|split[1]|split[2]|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|1.2.3|       1|       2|       3|
| 4..5|       4|    null|       5|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
```